# Access Database VB - Searching a database for most 'RECENT' record

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, visual-studio

I was wondering how I could change the code below, to allow me to search for the most recent record. I am creating a Hotel Booking System and want to use the most recent price in the database but at the moment, it is just searching using the labels which I don't want.

```
Dim str1 As String
Dim dbpassword As String = "123"
Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= E:\Computing\Hotel Booking System\Database\Hotel Booking System.accdb ;Jet OLEDB:Database Password =" & dbpassword & ";"
Dim MyConn As OleDbConnection
Dim dr As OleDbDataReader

Private Sub Information_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim PriceFound As String = False
    MyConn = New OleDbConnection

    MyConn.ConnectionString = connString

    MyConn.Open()

    str1 = ("SELECT * FROM [Prices] WHERE [Adult] = '" & LblPriceAdult.Text & "' AND [Child] = '" & LblPriceChild.Text & "'")

    Dim cmd1 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str1, MyConn)

    dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader

    While dr.Read()


        PriceFound = True
        DateDisplay = dr("ID").ToString
        AdultPrice = dr("Adult").ToString
        ChildPrice = dr("Child").ToString
        SingleRoom = dr("Single").ToString
        DoubleRoom = dr("Double").ToString
        FamilyRoom = dr("Family").ToString

        If PriceFound = True Then
            LblPriceAdult.Text = AdultPrice
            LblPriceChild.Text = ChildPrice
            LblPriceDoubleRoom.Text = DoubleRoom
            LblPriceFamilyRoom.Text = FamilyRoom
            LblPriceSingleRoom.Text = SingleRoom
        End If
    End While
    MyConn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a column in that table that suggests an edit date? or last modified? Or do you have an audit trail table that tracks this?

Comment: Yes, the ID column is being used for the date at the moment.

Comment: Well wouldnt you want to SELECT MAX(ID) FROM [Prices] ORDER BY ID DESC

Comment: basically you need to trap the most recent price entry. My order by might not be necessary but either way hope it helps

Comment: Ah oh course. Not been coding very long but that makes complete sense now. Thanks

Comment: glad it helped! I posted as answer just in case this solves your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your previous comments, you need to rewrite your SQL to trap the most recent record.

Try something like this:

```
 SELECT MAX(ID) FROM [Prices] ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Comment: I've tried this and the only way I get it to work is if I put quotes               str1 = ("SELECT `ID` FROM [Prices] ORDER BY `ID` DESC"). However it now comes up with 'Adult' as an error on the line  AdultPrice = dr("Adult").ToString

Comment: oh sorry yeah that was necessary. I forgot youre new to this, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answer above. However for the code above, it wouldn't search for the most recent so I changed `DESC` to `ASC`